# dissalow first option of drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, menu

How can I dissalow the **first** option of the following drop down menu (when "Go" is clicked, nothing should happen):

HTML :

```
<form name="form_name">
    <select name="ddmenu_name">
        <option>1st option (should do nothing)</option>
        <option value="link 1">link 1 name</option>
        <option value="link 2">link 2 name</option>
        <option value="link 3">link 3 name</option>
        <option value="link 4">link 4 name</option>
        <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Go" onClick="window.open(ddmenu_name.value,'newtab')">
    </select>
</form>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose of the first option is to provide a header, use an `optgroup`:

```
<select name="ddmenu_name"> 
    <optgroup label="1st option (should do nothing)">
        <option value="link 1">link 1 name</option> 
        <option value="link 2">link 2 name</option> 
        <option value="link 3">link 3 name</option> 
        <option value="link 4">link 4 name</option>
    </optgroup> 
</select>
```

Works in all major (old and new) browsers. Doesn't require JavaScript.

If that wasn't the intention you could do something like this:

```
var previous;
$('#ddmenu_id').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() === 'noselect') {
        $(this).val(previous);
    }
    else {
        previous = $(this).val();
    }
});
```

With HTML:

```
<select name="ddmenu_name" id="ddmenu_id"> 
<option value="noselect">1st option (should do nothing)</option> 
<option value="link 1">link 1 name</option> 
<option value="link 2">link 2 name</option> 
<option value="link 3">link 3 name</option> 
<option value="link 4">link 4 name</option> 
</select>
<input type="button" name="Submit" value="Go" onClick="window.open(ddmenu_name.value,'newtab')">
```

You can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WLDSy/).

Comment: But I want the "Go" link to open the links, not let them open as soon as a selection is made by the user...

Comment: @webmaniacgr That would still work. It doesn't open the link when they make the selection; I just omitted the button.

Comment: Yes, it does work & thank you, but still, the 1st option is displayed before user browses the available options, not the optgroup label...

Comment: @webmaniacgr Your previous comment isn't entirely clear. Which option are you using? optgroup or javascript? The optgroup will not allow the first option to be selected at all; so if you want the first item initially selected you should use the JavaScript solution.

Comment: So yes, I prefer the js solution - Can you adjust the js solution and add a "Go" link? Links should open in a new tab only after clicking that link, not just after users select an option.